# PowerShell splatting not working

Tags: powershell

I believe I'm missing something obvious, or misunderstanding the splatting feature of PowerShell.

I am using a *hash table* to pass arguments to a custom function, but it doesn't seem to take the arguments on even a simple example.

File: Test-Splat.ps1

```
function Test-Splat
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Greeting
    )
    $s = "$Greeting, $Name"
    Write-Host $s
}
```

Then attempting to execute this with splatting, asks for a value for the second parameter.

```
. .\Test-Splat.ps1
$Params = @{
    Name = "Frank"
    Greeting = "Hello"
}
Test-Splat $Params
```

Produces the following result

```
cmdlet Test-Splat at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Greeting:
```

If I use this directly without splatting, it works

```
Greeting: [PS] C:\>Test-Splat -Name "Frank" -Greeting "Hello"
Hello, Frank
```

If it's related, I'm doing this within Exchange Management Shell under PowerShell 3.0

```
[PS] C:\>$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are indeed missing something, and that is when you want to splat a variable as the parameters of a function or cmdlet you use the `@` symbol instead of the `$` symbol. In your example, the line where you splat the variable would look like this:

```
Test-Splat @Params
```

Comment: It's always something simple. Argh. That did it

Comment: I literally spent half an hour trying to figure out why splatting didn't work in my script. Thanks.